# How to authenticate with Active Directory using java in XPages

Tags: java, active-directory, xpages

I need to know if a user entered correct login information to Microsoft Active directory

I want the user to enter username and password on an xpage and it should only return if these values was entered correctly or not.

I know I can use ldap requests and send in credentials but have not seen any working solutions for this.

I need to use java as the code should be able to run on non windows servers

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches you can take:

- The easiest would be to link the AD to Domino using DirectoryAssistance and let users login using their AD credentials in the first place.
- If IIS is running on the AD server you could send an HTTP request using the Apache HTTPClient (and basic authentication) and see what's coming back
- The best working Java libraries are listed in the [Apache Directory project](http://directory.apache.org/api/). There you would do an LDAP query (e.g. the user herself)

Let us know which one works for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes your last point is the closest to what I want and still looking for an answer how to do it

Comment: Option 2 would be way easier to implement. Check with the AD admins if they have any IIS running somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JNDI to access the Active Directory. There are a lot of ressources on the web on how to do this, for example have a look at http://mhimu.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/active-directory-authentication-using-javajndi/

You have tagged the question as XPage, do you want to do the authentication from inside domino? In that case the domino server could do the authentication.

Comment: I solved it using ldap. I have implemented it into the intrapages app as a way to login using to intrapages using Active directory. http://intrapages.openntf.org